# Spring JPA entities not saving to database

Tags: java, spring, dao

I am facing some issues in Spring JPA. I successfully configured the Spring JPA project and  am able to run the project without having any exception.

I intension to save the entities to the database. But when I am running the project, it is neither saving to the database nor throwing any exceptions.

What could be the problem?  I have added many hiberate related jar files as well because it was throwing exceptions when I run. Now i am not getting any exception. But entities are not saved into database. I have attached my Spring configuration and Java classes.

**sprig configuration**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd"> 



    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:jdbc.properties"/>


        <!-- Connection Pool -->
     <bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClass}"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="user" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
     </bean>

     <!-- JPA EntityManagerFactory --> 
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
            p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                    <property name="database" value="${jdbc.database}"/>
                    <property name="showSql" value="${jdbc.showSql}"/>                  
            </bean>     
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Transaction manager for a single JPA EntityManagerFactory (alternative to JTA) -->
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
            p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/>


        <!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes for eg @Autowired-->
        <context:annotation-config/>

      <!-- enable the configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations  -->
      <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>



     <!-- <context:component-scan base-package="com.vemanchery.timesheet.dao"/> -->
    <!-- Implementation Class -->   
    <bean id="employeeDao" class="com.test.dao.impl.EmployeeDao" />
 <!-- services -->
    <bean id="employeeService" class="com.test.service.impl.EmployeeService" >
        <property name="employeeDao" ref="employeeDao"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**DAO**

```
package com.test.dao.impl;


import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;

import com.test.dao.interfaces.IEmployeeDao;
import com.test.model.interfaces.IEmployee;



//@Repository
//@Component
public class EmployeeDao implements IEmployeeDao{

    @PersistenceContext()
    private EntityManager entityManager ;

    @Override
    public boolean createEmployee(IEmployee employee) {     
        this.entityManager.persist(employee);

        return true;
    }


}
```

**Service Layer**

```
package com.test.service.impl;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.test.dao.impl.EmployeeDao;
import com.test.dao.interfaces.IEmployeeDao;
import com.test.model.interfaces.IEmployee;
import com.test.service.interfaces.IEmployeeService;

public class EmployeeService implements IEmployeeService{

    @Autowired
    IEmployeeDao employeeDao;

    public IEmployeeDao getEmployeeDao() {
        return employeeDao;
    }

    public void setEmployeeDao(IEmployeeDao employeeDao) {
        this.employeeDao = employeeDao;
    }

    /**
     * 
     */
    public boolean addEmployee(IEmployee employee){
        employeeDao.createEmployee(employee);       
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `@Transactional` annotation over your service class or method storing entities:

```
@Transactional
public boolean addEmployee(IEmployee employee){
    employeeDao.createEmployee(employee);       
    return false;
}
```

Adding `@Repository` over your DAO is also a good idea, but it is not causing your problems.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. I added the annotation. Now I am getting one exception Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy14 cannot be cast to com.test.service.impl.EmployeeService
 at main.Main.main(Main.java:16)

Comment: @user414967: Use `IEmployeeService` interface everwyhere rather than an implementation or enable *proxy-target-class* option.

Comment: @Tomaz It is working now.. Thanks a lot.. One more doubt,If Spring JPA means it has to be included any other ORM framework right?Without ORM cannot achieve the result right? Because it is a huge file now by including lots of jar files..

Comment: @user414967: first of all you are using [Spring support for JPA](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa), not the [Spring JPA](http://www.springsource.org/spring-data/jpa) project (which I can recommend). And yes, you need both JPA API and some JPA implementation like Hibernate. Unfortunately, the Hibernate JARs are quite heavy. If you have any further questions please open another question on SO - otherwise the comments and advices will get lost here.

Answer (score 0):

Enable annotation based processing for service and dao (I have never mixed xml config and annotation,so dont know if config setting is fine) and mark your service method

> **addEmployee @Transactional**

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I also faced such a problem. Two methods worked.
I added `super()` in all argument constructor method in Entity.

The other method is to replace the JPA Repository in the Repository file
I wrote PagingAndSortingRepository.

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Employee, Long> {

}
```

> long: empoloyeeId data type