# Spring Entities Not Saved To Database

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

We have set up the Spring Framework like this:

```
@Eager
public interface CatalogElementRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<CatalogElementEntity, Long> {

}

@Service
public class CatalogImpl implements CatalogManager {

    @Inject
    CatalogElementRepository catalogElementRepository;

    @Override
    public CatalogElement createCatalogElement(CatalogElementEntity catalogElement) {
    return this.catalogElementRepository.save(catalogElement);
    }
}

@Stateless
@Remote(CatalogManager.class)
public class CatalogManagerBean implements CatalogManager {

    @Inject
    CatalogManager delegate;

    @Override
    public CatalogElement createCatalogElement(CatalogElementEntity catalogElement) {
        return this.delegate.createCatalogElement(catalogElement);
    }
}
```

So whenever someone calls the method on the remote interface `createCatalogElement`, I'd assume the entity gets stored in the database. It does not (weirdly enough, `findOne` still returns the very same entity, but it can't be found via `findByProperty`).

[Other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289798/spring-jpa-entities-not-saving-to-database) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746460/spring-pagingandsortingrepository-find-by-name) said to add `@Transactional`, so I added `@javax.transaction.Transactional` and `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` on the methods and classes to be on the safe side, nothing worked.

What could be the problem?

I don't see any configuration files for the Spring Framework, but it's a legacy project, so they might just be hidden very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason using this class as a producer for the `EntityManager` helped:

```
public class SpringConfig {

@PersistenceUnit
EntityManagerFactory emf;

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

@Produces
@ApplicationScoped
public EntityManagerFactory createEntityManagerFactory() {
    return this.emf;
}

@Produces
public EntityManager createEntityManager() {
    return this.em;
}

public void close(@Disposes EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
    entityManagerFactory.close();
}

public void close(@Disposes EntityManager entityManager) {
    entityManager.close();
}
}
```